# SlideToggle как задать начальное состояние?

Tags: jquery, javascript

Сделал блок с SlideToggle, но при открытии страницы, этот тоггл в раскрывшемся виде. Как сделать, чтобы он был в закрытом виде, а при нажатии уже раскрылся? Ну чтобы механизм работал с закрытого положения

[Ссылка:](http://jsfiddle.net/G2Y46/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Прописать блоку в css свойство display:none либо скрыть его при загрузке .hide() или тем же .slideUp(0)